# Как правильно писать: всеведущее или всеведующее сознание?

Tags: орфография

Всеведущее или всеведующее сознание?

Comment: А "всевед**а**ющее" вы совсем не рассматриваете?

Answer (score 2):

Всеведущий - устаревшее слово, архаичный эпитет к слову Бог, сейчас употребляется только в религиозном контексте или ироничном (всезнайка).

Всеведующий - неверный вариант, существует словосочетание всё ведающий. Ведающий - знающий, это причастие, а всеведующий - искажённое слово, объединившее все ведающий и всеведущий. Сведущий - знающий, а всеведущий - тот, кто **всё** знает, обладает абсолютным знанием, он же всемогущий, т. е. Бог.

Всеведущий - прилагательное от глагола ведать в его исконном значении - "знать, видеть", а современное его значение - заведовать, управлять (*Ведает этим делом Иван Иванович...*). Оно образовалось позже. От страдательного причастия в**е**домый - известный, знакомый (глагол ведети - знать) - ведомость (весть, сообщение - фиксируется  с  14 века, потом список, сводка) и ведомство - (с 17 века известие, сведение, а затем "ведение, надзор, управление", потом "отрасль гос. управления").

Всеведующий иногда встречается в художественных текстах для речевой характеристики, чтобы показать, что это разговор простого человека, не очень грамотного, но выдающего себя за такового, грамотное же употребление одно - **всеведущий**, **обладающий всеведением.**

Comment: Словарь синонимов ошибается (https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/22008/%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9)?

Comment: Академик Лихачев ошибается или Нацкорпус врет: Пусть счет происходит чрезвычайно быстро, но в уме он все же ведется. Всеведующему Богу не надо считать ничего. Он держит одновременно «в сознании» миллионы и миллионы. [Д. С. Лихачев. Воспоминания (1995)]  ?

Comment: Да, действительно: то, что словари (напр. орфоэпический словарь для школьников) специально приводят как ошибку, можно найти не в одном десятке книг (чаще это старые книги и религиозные тексты) - как и два другие варианта. "Корпус" не так представителен в этом отношении, как гугл-букс.

Comment: Словарь синонимов не ошибается, он приводит все существующие слова всех стилей - и просторечные тоже, но нам-то нужен только нормированный литературный вариант. Насчёт Лихачёва сказать не могу, он человек грамотный, занимался философией. Единственное объяснение: писалось в советские времена, когда многие религиозные термины писались по слуху, для многих всеведущий и всеведующий - одно и то же. И потом, мы же рукопись не видели, как у него написано, может, это корректор поправил, как ему грамотным показалось.

Comment: Кстати, могли  внести ошибку при оцифровке. Я перешла на сайт, почитала его "Воспоминания", там есть ошибки, например, "Куокала" с одной "К".

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, оба варианта допустимы, хотя *всеведующий* — устаревающий вариант. Поиск в Нацкорпусе дает 253 вхождения для слова *всеведущий* и 10 вхождений для слова *всеведующий*, причем 7 из этих 10 датированы XIX веком и началом XX века. Не во всех современных словарях есть слово *всеведующий*.

> ― Позвольте, позвольте, а магнетизм? этот искусственный сон, делающий человека **всеведующим**? ― Я не верю в сны, ― отвечал Северин. [А. Ф. Вельтман. Аленушка (1836)]
>
> Маленький сухой человечек, крылатый, **всеведущий** и грозный, парил над ними. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Хранитель древностей, часть 1 (1964)]

Answer (score 1):

Слово "*всеведующий*" не имеет убедительных оснований для своего образования: напрашивается сопоставление с близким по форме "заведующий" - это слово образовано от "заведовать"; слова же "ведовать" нет, есть только *ведать, ведает* и т. п. В "Словаре трудностей произношения и ударения в современном русском языке" вариант "*всеведу**ю**щий*" приведён в скобках с пометкой "*неправильно*". В словаре **Даля** можно найти слово "**всеведающий**" - оно приводится в числе синонимов слова "всевещный", в соотв. статье.

Что касается слова "**всеведущий**", то в словарях эта форма толкуется как "(*эпитет бога; церк.*)" (Ушаков) или приводится с пометкой "(*устар. и ирон.*)" (Ожегов). Если обратиться к современной издательской практике (напр., поискать среди *книг* гуглом), то видно, что в сочетании с "**сознанием**", в качестве эпитетов Будды и в других текстах, не связанных с христианскими канонами, конкурируют две формы: **всеведущий** и **всеведающий** (**Блаватская**, **Проханов** и др., часть переводов Шри Ауробиндо и т. п.). Поэтому, на мой взгляд, применительно к **сознанию** есть выбор между изначально религиозным и светским вариантами -  смотря какой оттенок придаётся **Вс. сознанию**, исследовательский или почтительно-религиозный (иронический смысл "всеведущего" отпадает).

Comment: Все логично, но как быть с академиком Лихачевым (см. мой комментарий к  ответу Людмилы)?

Comment: В сочетании с "сознанием" (как в вопросе) слова "всеведующий" у него нет; в других текстах именно такого сочетания мне тоже не попадалось (обычно в книгах оно замыкается на Бога или на личность).

Comment: Да, но Вы и Людмила утверждате (и это выглядит логично), что такого слова вообще нет. А у Лихачева и других оно есть (вопреки логике).  Как это объяснить?

Comment: Я лишь сослался на два источника, которые специальной оговоркой, вероятно, отстаивают современную норму, с которой нужно считаться. Лихачёв в своей работе имел дело со старыми религиозными текстами, в которых это слово было широко представлено. Как оно образовалось и столь широко распространилось - вопрос интересный, хотя он и за пределами темы **Вс. сознания**. В каком-то педагогическом пособии о произносительных навыках у детей это слово ставится в ряд таких (будущий, всеведущий...), для которых у некоторых учащихся наблюдается склонность добавлять "ю" при произнесении.

Comment: http://rus-gos.spbu.ru/index.php/words/show/3398

Answer (score 0):

1) Правильно: **всеведущее сознание.**

Из словаря: **ВСЕВЕДУЩИЙ**,  **Книжн**. Обо всём осведомлённый; всезнающий. В-ие корреспонденты. Он хотел доказать всем, что он всеведущ.

ВСЕВЕДУЩИЙ, -ого; м. [с прописной буквы] В христианстве: **одно из имён Бога**.

Слово **словарное**, оно образовано по **нестандартной** схеме: чередование глагольного суффикса ОВА/У, но при этом в форме причастия опущена буква Ю, что соответствует произносительному варианту, сравнить: след/ова/ть ― след/у/ют ― след/у/ющ/ий.

Словарными являются и слова ***сведущий*** и ***несведущий***. Соответствующий глаголы с приставкой С в языке отсутствует.

2) **Грамматическая справка**

В русском языке существует глагол ***ведать***, а форма "ведовать" используется только в приставочном варианте: ***заведовать*** ― заведуют ― заведующий, ***проповедовать*** ― проповедуют ― проповедующий,  исповедовать ― исповедуют ― исповедующий.

Глагол ***исповедовать***  двувидовой, существует еще глагол ***исповедать*** (только сов. вид). ИСПОВЕДАТЬ, -аю, -аешь; св. Разг. =Исповедовать (1-2 зн.). И. в грехах. И. грех священнику.

Глагол ***ведать*** имеет много приставочных форм, все они образуют **видовую пару в суффиксами А/ЫВА:** выведать ― выведывать, наведаться ― наведываться, отведать ― отведывать, проведать ― проведывать, разведать ― разведывать.

3) **История вопроса**

Слово ***всеведущий*** уже в словаре Ушакова 1935 года писалось именно так. ВСЕВЕДУЩИЙ, всеведущая, всеведущее. Всё знающий (эпитет бога; церк.).
|| Обо всем осведомленный, всезнайка ("разг." ирон.).

**У Ожегова**  ВСЕВЕ́ДУЩИЙ, (устар. и ирон.). Всё знающий, обо всём осведомлённый. Всеведущие корреспонденты. Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова.

В современном словаре у слова ***всеведущий***  пометка **книжн**. Это означает, что оно может иметь любое значение (религиозное, ироническое или нейтральное).

Из Нацкорпуса:

**Всеведущее**, и познающее одним взором без всяких размышлений...  [архиепископ Платон (Левшин). Катихизис десятый (1758)]

.. бог есть существо **всеведущее** и святейшее;[Л. Н. Толстой. Исследование догматического богословия (1880)]

Но (**один пример**): ...Бог, как всеблагое и **всеведующее** существо... [С. Л. Франк. Смысл жизни (1925)]

4) **Вывод**

Таким образом, **орфография слова закрепилась уже давно**, еще до реформы 1956 года (хотя до этого времени колебания еще были возможны),  а менялись только стилевые характеристики.

**Поэтому нет причин для другого  написания** слова ***всеведущий*** в любых сочетаниях и текстах.